# Open Vim from a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rake

I am creating a journal application for personal notes and have the following in my `Rakefile`:

```
task :new do
  entry_name = "Entries/#{Time.now.to_s.gsub(/[-\ :]+/, '.').gsub(/.0500+/,'')}.md"
  `touch #{entry_name}`
  `echo "# $(date)" >> #{entry_name}`
end
```

The last part I would like to include is the opening of the Vim text editor but I am unable to figure out how to open it as if I called it directly from the bash terminal.

I have tried:

```
vim #{entry_name}
```

but unfortunately I think both of those open it as a background process.

I have been referencing "[6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)".

Comment: I'm surprised `exec` doesn't work, as it should. What happens when you use that method?

Comment: The script just ended and I wend back to the bash prompt.  Vim didn't leave a `.entry_name.swap` file so I do not believe the program is lingering anywhere.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall  Wait... `exec "vim #entry_name"` did work!! Wana put that in an answer and I'll check it.

Comment: Likewise, if you want to run ruby code after you're done with `vim` use `system` instead of `exec`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As in the [article you referenced](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html), `` ` ``s run the command in a *subshell* within the current process, but the real problem is that it's trying to take the output from the command run as well, which doesn't play nice with Vim.

You can either:

- Use `exec` to *replace* the current process with the new one (note that the Ruby/Rake process will end once you've called `exec`, and nothing after it will run).
- Use `system` to create a subshell like `` ` ``s, but avoids the problem of trying to grab Vim's stdout. Unlike `exec`, after Vim terminates, Ruby will continue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the tty as standard input for backspaces etc. to work well in vim:

```rb
exec("</dev/tty vim a b")
```

---

obviously the backtick (`` ` ``) didn't work but I was having issues with `system`/`exec` from a script.

first I get `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`, and then I see `^?` when I use backspace.